# Scale Fragment / ViewGroup to fit screen with animation

Tags: android, animation, android-fragments

I have two fragments that takes 50% of screen height. Need to scale one of them to fit screen with animation. How to do that ? I consider use animation on fragment transition somehow or maybe make some view animation on FrameLayout ?

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/main_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/f1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"/>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/f2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: is it not working (view not divided into 50% from this xml) ?

Comment: What do you mean "not working" ? Both fragment have 50% of screen. Need to make one of them to fit 100% by animation.